Is the standard or the 4 year visa validity better for F1?
When trying to schedule an interview at the US embassy, I get the question whether I want to apply for a visa with standard validity (19 months) or a 4-year visa. According to my I-20, the length of my program is 196 weeks. Which option should I pick?
If the latter, I'm also told to write on my DS-160 confirmation page that I'd like a 4-year visa - which I don't understand how I can even do (there's not field for that on the confirmation page). Is there any advantage to picking the 4-year option?

Does this answer your question? Standard Visa Validity for F1?
